# Can I control the volume of a chromecast while a different app/device is the one connected to it?

Tags: chromecast

Device A, device B, and a chromecast are on the same wifi.
If device A is using app A (Youtube perhaps) to connect and cast to the chromecast, is there an API that can be used by App B on Device B to modify the volume of the chromecast?

If no, how about a App B on Device A? Is it able to modify the volume of the chromecast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to a cast device without launching any receiver application. Once connected, you should be able to use [Cast.CastApi.setVolume()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastApi.html#public-methods) method to set/change the volume.